What was the global earth temperature before the industrial revolution?
I keep seeing that the rise in global temperature was measured against pre-industrial times. However, I can't find a global average for this period (circa 1700 to 1850). Because the Little Ice Age or the Holocene climatic optimum will probably not be a reference. What were the conditions?

According to this article from NOAA the 20th Century world average temperature is pegged at 13.9°C(~57°F) with the pre-industrial average a little lower at 13.73°C(~56.7°F).

And a previous se-Earth Science question that was answered citing the same NOAA information, may be found here. Based on existing information regarding the estimated warming in the industrial period, the average temperature for pre-industrial period provided in that answer was determined by simple math to be about 13.68°C. This corroborates the answer by Ash, above.
